# use of cssselect for fetching the url using lxml

Tags: python, lxml

I am working on a url & I want to fetch the particular link.
but there are number of tables present.
how can I work on it within one or two lines of code using lxml?

```
url = 'http://www.bnm.gov.my/index.php?ch=109&pg=294&mth=3&yr=2012&eId=box1'
```

I want to download excel for
table 2.1 Interest Rates: Banking Institutions

I dont understand how to work when there are number of tables and tds and trs present in an html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first, there's no unique identifier for that link or that table row, so won't be able to fetch it with `cssselect` and you won't be able to fetch it without already knowing what part of the URL or title is going to be.

Let's say you're going to match the section number `2.1`. Looking at the page, the section number is always in the first cell in a row. Once you find the correct cell, you can traverse to its second sibling, which should contain the link, then get the URL from the link.

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> url = "http://www.bnm.gov.my/index.php?ch=109&pg=294&mth=3&yr=2012&eId=box1"
>>> ufile = urllib2.urlopen(url)
>>> root = etree.parse(ufile, etree.HTMLParser())
>>> for e in root.getiterator('tr'):
...     fc = e[0]       # first child
...     if fc.tag == 'td' and fc.text == '2.1':
...         link = fc.getnext().getnext()[0]  # first child of 2nd sibling
...         print link.attrib["href"]
...
files/publication/msb/2012/3/xls/2.1.xls
```